# Brightness settings stuck after computer shut down in bootcamp

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp

As I was going to sleep for the night I decided I didn't want to shut my computer off completely and so I instead opted for turning the brightness settings all the way down in order to keep the computer up (I know, pretty dumb right?) . However, upon waking up i noticed the cord wasn’t attached and the computer shut down while I was sleep and now I cant boot up windows without the screen dimming down after the logo goes away. I’be tried using the brightness buttons to turn it up to no avail and I’ve also tried just entering my passwoed in hopes I could use the buttons but theybwont work. Im using a 2012 Macbook Pro with Windows 10 installed. I’ve tried hard resetting to access the recovery mode but f8 sadly wont work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it seems that from your post you haven't tried to turn the brightness settings up

Comment: ive updated it sorry about that

Comment: have you tried changing it from the action center?

Comment: I wish but its as if my brightness settings are locked on the windows side and im getting no response once it goes out

Comment: hmmm... have you tried resetting the SMC?

Comment: also try resetting the NVRAM as well

Answer (score 1):

Just plug in your charger, bump the brightness up (not with the keys), disconnect charger, boom.